# XSLT 1.0 - adding a specific sequence number to a duplicate value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a list of values and need to be able to check if a duplicate exists and if so, I need to add a "1" after the first duplicate, a "2" after a second duplicate.

My XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" language="nl_NL" timezone="Europe/Paris">
<Declaration wayBillNumber="102956715"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="102956715"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="151975168"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152003915"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152005173"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152005964"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152011491"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152011491"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="183875206"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="204305618"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152011491"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="210642574"/>
</data>
```

The output should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" language="nl_NL" timezone="Europe/Paris">
<Declaration wayBillNumber="102956715"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="102956715-1"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="151975168"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152003915-2"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152005173"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152005964"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152011491"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152011491-1"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="183875206"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="204305618"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="152011491-2"/>
<Declaration wayBillNumber="210642574"/>
</data>
```

I am able to see if a duplicate occurs and then do something with it, but what I can't seem to find out is how add the sequence number to it. When I use the line below, only "-1" is added after each duplicate value.

```
<xsl:attribute name="wayBillNumber">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="preceding::*/Declaration/@wayBillNumber=current()/Declaration/@wayBillNumber"><xsl:value-of select="Declaration/@wayBillNumber"/>-<xsl:value-of select="count((.|preceding-sibling::Declaration/@wayBillNumber)[not(Declaration/@wayBillNumber = preceding-sibling::Declaration/@wayBillNumber)])"/></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="Declaration/@wayBillNumber"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
```

I'm only able to use XSLT 1.0. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the order of the output matter? If not, I would suggest you do [proper grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), then use the `position()` function to number the items in each group.

Comment: P.S. There is something very "wrong" about this requirement: if the `wayBillNumber` values are significant, then you should not be modifying them. Instead, you should add another property to the `Declaration` and populate it with overall unique values - with no regard to the `wayBillNumber` sequence. OTOH, if the `wayBillNumber` values can be modified willy-nilly, then why not simply append an overall unique value to **all** of them?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Just adding a unique value to all of them will be the nicest solution, but the receiving system will not change their datamodel for this, so I just have to make due.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick fix, you could try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Declaration">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::Declaration[@wayBillNumber=current()/@wayBillNumber])" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="wayBillNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="@wayBillNumber"/>
            <xsl:if test="$i">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('-', $i)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this is a very inefficient method because every `Declaration` needs to go over all its preceding siblings.

Comment: Very nice indeed. I'm using this. Thanks Michael!